# Evaluating $ \int^{\infty}_0\frac{\ln x}{x^2+\pi^2} ~dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The question is

> Evaluate 
>   $$ \int \limits^{\infty}_0\dfrac{\ln x}{x^2+\pi^2} dx $$

I have no idea what to do.Tried integration by parts, didn't work.

Help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Assuming the presence of $dx,$  set $x=\pi\tan y$

Comment: Did you try partial fraction decomposition followed by integration by parts ?

Comment: Partial fractions for this? How would that work? (Unless $i = \sqrt{-1}$ is involved).

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, That gives me $\int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac{1}{\pi}\ln(\pi tany) dy $. Now I dont know how to proceed.

Comment: I don't think you can find an antiderivative in terms of elementary functions. This type of integral is usually computed by contour integration around a "keyhole contour" in the complex plane (although for this particular integral, there is a "trick" method as shown in Ron's answer).

Comment: $$I_a(n)=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{x^2+a^2}dx\qquad\iff\qquad I'_\pi(0)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{x^2+\pi^2}dx$$

Comment: @VijayRaghavan, please find my answer below

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, thanks!

Answer (score 14):

**Method I**

Split the integration region as follows:

$$\int_0^{\pi} dx \frac{\log{x}}{x^2+\pi^2} + \int_{\pi}^{\infty} dx \frac{\log{x}}{x^2+\pi^2}$$

In the second integral, sub $x=\pi^2/y$ and get that the integral is

$$\int_0^{\pi} dx \frac{\log{x}}{x^2+\pi^2} + \pi^2 \int_0^{\pi} \frac{dy}{y^2} \frac{\log{\pi^2/y}}{\pi^2+\pi^4/y^2}$$

or after some cancellation

$$\int_0^{\pi} dx \frac{\log{\pi^2}}{x^2+\pi^2}  = \frac12 \log{\pi}$$

**Method II**

As intimated in the comments, we may use the residue theorem.  Use a keyhole contour of radius $R$ $C$ about the positive real axis and consider the integral

$$\oint_C dz \frac{\log^2{z}}{z^2+\pi^2}$$

The integral over the circular arc vanishes as $R \to\infty$ and by the residue theorem, we are left with

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\log^2{x}}{x^2+\pi^2} - \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{(\log{x}+i 2 \pi)^2}{x^2+\pi^2} = i 2 \pi \left [\frac{(\log{\pi}+i \pi/2)^2}{i 2 \pi}- \frac{(\log{\pi}+i 3\pi/2)^2}{i 2 \pi}\right ]$$

or

$$-i 4 \pi \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\log{x}}{x^2+\pi^2}+ 4 \pi^2 \int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{1}{x^2+\pi^2} = -i 2 \pi \log{\pi} + 2 \pi^2$$

The respective terms on the right on each side cancel, and we are left with

$$\int_0^{\infty} dx \frac{\log{x}}{x^2+\pi^2} = \frac12 \log{\pi}$$

Answer (score 4):

An alternative, $a > 0$:

$$\displaystyle\begin{align*} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{x^2 + a^2}dx & \overset{x\mapsto a \tan x}= \frac{1}{a}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln a \ dx + \frac{1}{a}\underbrace{\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln \tan x \ dx}_{=0} \\ & = \frac{\ln a}{a}\cdot \frac{\pi}{2} \end{align*}$$

The latter integral can be shown to be equal to 0 by splitting it up like so:

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln \tan x\ dx = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln \sin x \ dx - \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln \cos x \ dx$$

and $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln \sin x \ dx \overset{x\mapsto \frac{\pi}{2} - x}= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln \cos x \ dx$$

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} + \pi^{2}}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> \color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} + \pi^{2}}\,\dd x}&=
> {1 \over \pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{\pi x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x
> ={1 \over \pi}\,\ln\pars{\pi}\
> \overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x^{2} + 1}}^{\ds{=\ {\pi \over 2}}}\
> +\ {1 \over \pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=\half\,\ln\pars{\pi}
> + {1 \over \pi}
> \overbrace{\quad\bracks{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x\
> +\
> \underbrace{\quad\int_{1}^{0}{\ln\pars{1/x} \over \pars{1/x}^{2} + 1}\,\pars{-\,{\dd x \over x^{2}}}\quad}_{\ds{=-\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x}}}\quad}^{\ds{=\ 0}}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{\large\half\,\ln\pars{\pi}}
> \end{align}

Answer (score 3):

As I've hinted, setting $x=\pi\tan y $

We have $$ \int \limits^{\infty}_0\dfrac{\ln x}{x^2+\pi^2} dx =\frac1\pi\int_0^{\frac\pi2}(\ln\pi\tan y)dy $$

Using $$\int_a^b f(y)dy=\int_a^b f(a+b-y)dy$$

$$\pi I=\int_0^{\frac\pi2}(\ln\pi\tan y)dy=\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\ln\pi\tan\left(\frac\pi2+0- y\right)dy=\int_0^{\frac\pi2}(\ln\pi\cot y)dy $$

$$\implies \pi(I+I)=\int_0^{\frac\pi2}(\ln\pi\tan y)dy+\int_0^{\frac\pi2}(\ln\pi\cot y)dy$$

$$=\int_0^{\frac\pi2}(\ln\pi\tan y+\ln\pi\cot y)dy$$

$$=\int_0^{\frac\pi2}[\ln(\pi\tan y\cdot\pi\cot y)]dy$$

$$2\pi\cdot I=\ln \pi^2\int_0^{\frac\pi2}dy $$

Can you take it home from here?

Answer (score 1):

Using Gordon‘s wonderful substitution $x=\frac{\pi^2}{y}$, we can directly find the integral,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{x^2+\pi^2} d x 
= & \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln \pi^2-\ln y}{\pi^2+y^2} d y\\=&\frac{1}{2}  \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln \pi^2}{\pi^2+y^2} d y\\=&\frac{\ln \pi }{2} 
\end{aligned}
$$